# Python - Criação de Lista

Tags: python, tabela-html

Não estou conseguindo imprimar a tabela de dados, está dando apenas os dados do primeiro input, e não consegui enxergar onde está o problema, sou iniciante e fazendo projetos simples.

```
print ('----------------------------------------------------')
print ('                 CONTROLE DE PLANTEL                ')
print ('----------------------------------------------------')

id_do_lote = str(input('Identificação do lote:'))
numero_de_animais = (input('Número de animais no lote:'))
lista_dos_animais = []
lista_de_pesagem = []


i = 1
while i <= int(numero_de_animais):
    id_animal = str(input ('ID do animal #' + str(i)+ ' '))
    lista_dos_animais.append(id_animal)
    i += 1

i = 1
while i <= int(numero_de_animais):
    peso_animal = float(input ('Peso do animal #' + str (i)+ ' '))
    lista_de_pesagem.append(peso_animal)
    i += 1

for name_animal in lista_dos_animais:
    dados_name_animal = name_animal

for peso_animal in lista_de_pesagem:
    dados_peso_animal = peso_animal

def criarTabela ():
    print ('----------------------------------------------------')
    print ('                 Lista de dados                     ')
    print ('----------------------------------------------------')
    print ('%s:\t\t\t%f' % (dados_name_animal, dados_peso_animal))
    print('-----------------------------------------------------')

criarTabela()
```

Comment: *Não estou conseguindo imprimar a tabela de dados...* seu programa não usa tabelas.

Comment: aqui está o erro ```dados_name_animal = name_animal```e esse ```dados_peso_animal = peso_animal```

Answer (score 0):

O erro esta nos dois `for`. Em vez de adicionar os nomes e pesos dos animais, você apenas esta criando as variaveis e colocando nela os valores, isso dentro de um for então, a cada iteração o valor anterior é substituido, e fica só o ultimo.

No metodo `criarTabela()` você deve criar um loop pois está imprimindo uma lista.

```
dados_name_animal = []
for name_animal in lista_dos_animais:
    dados_name_animal.append(name_animal)
dados_peso_animal = []
for peso_animal in lista_de_pesagem:
    dados_peso_animal.append(peso_animal)


def criarTabela():
    print('----------------------------------------------------')
    print('                 Lista de dados                     ')
    print('----------------------------------------------------')
    for i in range(len(dados_peso_animal)):
        print(str(dados_name_animal[i]) + ':  ' + str(dados_peso_animal[i]))
        print('-----------------------------------------------------')


criarTabela()
```

Comment: Putz, era isso mesmo Bernardo, obrigado! Na parte do curso que eu estou não apareceu essas funções do range e lens...